# How to get the ellipsized text in a TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, truncate

How do I get the text that has been truncated by Android into an ellipsis?

I have a textview:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Um longo texto aqui de exemplo" />
```

On a device this TextView is shown like this:

`"Um longo texto a..."`

How do I get the rest of the text?

I am looking for something like `getRestOfTruncate()` which would return "qui de exemplo".

Comment: I fixed your question's title and text. I wish I had an answer for you, but I don't think there is a way to do this. What is the use case here?

Comment: Thanks @AustynMahoney, should probably be something done to make it, else, I will build something, the problem is that it will be much more difficult, but if I do post here

Comment: Use `android:text="@string/full_text"` in xml layout, and `getString(R.string.full_text)` in java code whenever you need it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
String text = (String) textView.getText().subSequence(textView.getLayout().getEllipsisStart(0), textView.getText().length());
```

Comment: Work perfect but i need insert your code inside a postRunnable because first the textview must be designed, in finishi i make this: new Handler().postDelayed(runnable with your code,1 milissegundo);

Comment: This only works if I have `android:singleLine="true"`.  If I set it to `false` and set `android:maxLines` to some number other than `, then this method always returns the entire text as if it were not ellipsised at all.

Answer (score 3):

My solution. Kotlin extension function:

```
fun TextView.getEllipsizedText(): String {
if (text.isNullOrEmpty()) return ""
return layout?.let {
    val end = textContent.text.length - textContent.layout.getEllipsisCount(maxLines - 1)
    return text.toString().substring(0, end)
} ?: ""
}
```

Comment: This is not working since EllipsisCount returns only for a single line not the whole Text!

Answer (score 1):

Using textView.getLayout().getEllipsisStart(0) only works if android:singleLine="true"

Here is a solution that will work if android:maxLines is set:

```
public static String getEllipsisText(TextView textView) {
    // test that we have a textview and it has text
    if (textView==null || TextUtils.isEmpty(textView.getText())) return null;
    Layout l = textView.getLayout();
    if (l!=null) {
        // find the last visible position
        int end = l.getLineEnd(textView.getMaxLines()-1);
        // get only the text after that position
        return textView.getText().toString().substring(end);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Remember: this works after the view is already visible.

**Usage:**

```
textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            Log.i("test" ,"EllipsisText="+getEllipsisText(textView));
        }
    });
```