# Android: Detect where textView (with Ellipsize=none) would have ellipsed, and get the extra text

Tags: android, textview

In my Android app, I have a textView that has a limited length and a string that is much larger. I need to display as much of the string in the textView as possible and then detect exactly what text is left over. The tricky part is that unlike this previous post ([How to get the ellipsized text in a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041966/how-to-get-the-ellipsized-text-in-a-textview)), I can't have an ellipse show in the textView. The example in that post relies on the ellipse.

Does anyone know of a way to either get the overflow text without relying on the ellipse (.getEllipsisStart()), or to hide the ellipse from appearing?

Comment: I played around some more and found a not-so-elegant solution, but it appears to work. First, I put the string into the textView with ellipsize enabled. Second, I used .getEllipsisStart() to determine where the string ellipsized. Third, I dynamically disabled ellipsize for the textView.

I'm guessing there is a more straight-forward way of doing this...

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846113/android-word-wrap-without-breaking-or-ellipsizing/22852448#22852448) I provided a solution on how the last word (complete one without ...) can be found in TextView. Maybe you could pick up the idea and modify it.